# Character occurrence in string (Case Sensitive)

Tags: c, logic

A string is passed as input, an integer denoting the alphabetic position value, And a character 'u' or 'l' which denotes upper or lower case are passed as input. The output should give the number of N value alphabet (case sensitive) occurrence.

Code is working, 3 Hidden test cases passes and 3 Hidden test cases failed out of 6 hidden test cases. Please do help !! :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int N,Count=0,i,len;
    char Ar[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'},M,Str[1000];
    scanf("%[^\n]",Str);
    //printf("%s",Str);
    scanf("%d ",&N);
    //printf("%d",N);
    scanf("%c",&M);
    //printf("%c",M);

    len=strlen(Str);
    if(M=='L' || M=='l')
     {
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(Str[i]==Ar[N-1])
            {
                Count++;
            }
        }
     }
    else if(M=='U' || M=='u')
    {
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {

            if(Str[i]==toupper(Ar[N-1]))
            {
                Count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(Count==0)
    {
        printf("-1");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d",Count);
    }

}
```

Comment: if you have failing test cases, then they should point you to the problem. What do you mean by "hidden" test cases ?

Comment: Sir, we're given chance to review the hidden test case with points. But, it's too complex. Can you please try to find what's wrong with the logic instead of down voting?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of input and expected output? What do you mean with "reviewing the test case with points"? Are the test cases too complex for you?

Comment: @VishnuPriya : I didn't downvote, nor am I here to do your work for you. If you have a specific question, you'll have a better chance of getting help.

Comment: In your array, the letters h, i and j are duplicated, so a test case where `N > 10` will not work. You should also check whether the index N is valid.

Comment: Please show at least some examples of input and expected and actual output.

Comment: Maybe not directly related to your problem: Instead of `char Ar[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'}` (which is wrong BTW, there is at least a duplicate h, unless it is intentional, but then you shoud put a comment), you should generate the array dynamically with 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VishnuPriya , I think the mistake is with your array `char Ar[26]` .Few characters are repeating in that array **`*('h','i','j')*`**.

Modify the array to :-

```
char Ar[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
```

Make sure that none of characters are repeating.